# How to send message to room XMPP iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire

I'm sending messages to the room with this code:

```
[xmppRoom sendMessageWithBody:messageStr];
```

xmppRoom is my current room. Here is send msg :

```
SEND: <message to="ios@conference.localhost" type="groupchat"><body>Hey man are you there </body></message>
```

and Receive Message :

```
RECV: <message xmlns="jabber:client" to="user1@localhost/2epj2q8l5t" type="groupchat" from="ios@conference.localhost/user1"><body>Hey man are you there </body></message>
```

I'm sending messages to the room, but the message gets back to me, it won't deliver to other user, and yes i can get message successfully from room.

So what is wrong there?

Comment: It's normal in groupchat a message get back simply because openfire deliver to all users in chat at "sending" time. How many other users are in chat while you send this message?

Comment: both online while you send the message? With same client?